# Solr: Checking which terms are already available in the Solr index from a list of terms

Tags: solr, indexing

I have a list of terms that I want to check which of them are already available in the Solr index

for e.g I have a `<**field** name="word" type="string" index="true" store="true">` which indexes the terms.

And I have list of words e.g. Honda, Civic, 2001.

I want to check which of these terms are already available in the index. Is there any good efficient way of doing it rather than sending request one by one for the word Honda, Civic and 2001 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can submit a facet query like the following:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=word
  &facet.limit=-1
```

This will return all the unique terms in the word field as well a count of the number of each term that is found in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you can use this but 'luke' can give you top-terms for that field in browser interface.

> http:/localhost:8983/solr/index_name/admin/**luke**?fl=**word**

Comment: Luke will give all terms not the terms which are indexed i saw many terms which were not indexed but returns din list like "the" or "is"